# Dynamically changing a method name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
headerCaptions.push(localization.SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST1);
headerCaptions.push(localization.SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST2);
headerCaptions.push(localization.SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST3);
```

`headerCaptions` is an array. The `localization` object contains string values.

I want to generate this dynamically, i.e. map through x number of times, the number of the object parameter increasing by one with each iteration. For example to make 4 would make the final method call `SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST4` and so on.

I am happy to use vanilla js or the new ES6 syntax.

Comment: You seem to be looking for [*square bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), something like `headerCaptions.push(localization['SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST' + i];`.

Comment: How is your question title anywhere related to your question body?

Answer (score 2):

You can use bracket notation in objects, to use variables like this:

```
headerCaptions.push(localization['SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST'+i]);
```

Then you can use a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    headerCaptions.push(localization['SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST'+i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 syntax, you could call something like this:

```
const n = 4;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  headerCaptions.push(localization[`SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST${i}`])
}
```

Since JavaScript object attributes can be accessed either by calling `object.property` or `object['property']`, we can programatically access the attributes of `location` that are of interest by manipulating a string.

The `` syntax uses string interpolation, allowing you to insert computed values / variables into a string by surrounding it by `${}`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can access object properties using either the dot syntax (which you have used in your example) or the substring syntax, which looks like this:

```
headerCaptions.push(localization["SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST1"]);
```

Since the square brackets just contain a string, it's possible to dynamically generate them.

```
headerCaptions.push(localization["SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST" + i]);
```

Now all you need to do is loop through your numbers.

```
var i = 1;
var il = 4;
while (i < il) {

    headerCaptions.push(localization["SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST" + i]);
    i += 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){

    if(!localization.hasOwnProperty("SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST"+i))
       break;

    headerCaptions.push(localization["SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST"+i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `a.b` is equivalent to `a['b']`, so you can just do

```
for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  headerCaptions.push(localization['SCREEN_EPISODE_INITIATION_HEADER_REQUEST' + i]);
}
```

However, it might be better to just store these values in an array.